# Compute loss/inch for (differential) T-line from s-parameters?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, differential, signal-integrity, s-parameters

I have the 4-port s-parameters of 2 PCB boards, where each board consists of a differential transmission-line with SMA connectors on either end.

The only difference between the boards is their trace length is different.

Can I accurately compute the insertion loss of the PCB trace in dB/inch? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S11 is input return loss. S22 is output return loss (output driven and reflected energy measured). S21 is forward gain, input driven and output power measured. S12 is reverse gain, output driven and input power measured.

You have various measurements, including S21 for 2 different lengths, for various frequencies. Did you normalize the S-param measurements, before measuring the PCBs? Normalization allows de-embedding the item-under-test from the cables and SMA connectors. If you did "normalize", can you tell the difference?

Suppose at 1GHz, for 1 meter the S21 is -0.5dB, and for 2 meters the S21 is -1.2dB. Does this mean that PCB, at 1GHz, has 0.7dB loss per meter? I think so.

[EDIT Read Mike's discussion below, in the comment. ]

Comment: Only if the mismatch loss is negligible. The transmission lines maybe of any characteristic impedance.

Comment: @ Mike Math for that?

Comment: If you assume that there is no energy radiated from the transmission line, then the following holds true (since the TL is passive) : $$|S_{11}|^2 + |S_{21}|^2 + |(loss)| ^2=1$$ it's slightly more complicated than this for differential signals since you should take the mode conversion into consideration.